# Unable to access to services in tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

When i try to invoke a container via

```
self::bootKernel();
$container = static::getContainer();
```

I get an error "LogicException: Could not find service "test.service_container". Try updating the "framework.test" config to "true"." Even though my config/packages/test/framework.php looks like this

```
return static function (FrameworkConfig $framework): void
{
    $framework
        ->test(true);

    $session = $framework->session();

    $session
        ->storageFactoryId('session.storage.factory.mock_file');
};
```

I can get to the container itself via

```
$container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
```

however, I cannot access any of my services. Decause I get an error every time "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "App\User\Infrastructure\Repository\UserRepository" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead."

Comment: Considering that there are at least a dozen or so recent identical questions out there, perhaps you save a bit of time by detailing which of the various solutions you have tried?

Comment: If you want to get access to your service from `Container` you have to make it public:
`# config/services.yaml
services:
   session.storage.factory.mock_file:
        public: true`

Comment: so far I tried to make the services public, I also created a dedicated file services_test.php but none of the solutions help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by modifying the "configureContainer" method in the kernel. It was necessary to add import services_test.php

```
$container->import($this->getConfigDir() . '/{services}_' . $this->environment . '.php');
```